# How to write access query to find time interval in the same userid

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table look like this:

```
     userid    pagetag     time
      111       1-2      19:08:02
      111       1-2      19:09:03
      111       1-2      19:10:11
      111       1-2      19:10:12
      113       1-2      13:02:04
      113       1-2      13:04:03
      113       1-2      13:04:08
      115       1-2      14:08:56
      115       1-2      14:14:22
      115       1-2      14:14:25
```

I want to get the userid where the time interval is more than 60 second in the same userid. The result look like this:

```
     userid     count
       111       2
       113       1
       115       1
```

Comment: You probably will need an analytical function to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    LogTable.userid, 
    Count(LogTable.time) AS Over60
FROM 
    LogTable
WHERE 
    DateDiff("s", [time],
        Nz((Select Top 1 [time] 
            From LogTable As T 
            Where T.userid = LogTable.userid And T.time > LogTable.time
            Order By T.time Desc),[time])) > 60
GROUP BY 
    LogTable.userid;
```